# SQL: Query from two tables, can't keep groups in single row

Tags: sql, group-by, row

I have two databases, first one being 
ItemStatus:

```
ItemNr  Status
452 
567     ok
237     ok
```

the other one is

ItemList:

```
 Team   Type1   Type2   Type3
 Team1   345        
 Team2           567    
 Team3   237             452
```

I want to obtain the next combined query:

```
Team    Type1   Type1Status Type2 Type2Status   Type3 Type3Status   
Team1   345         
Team2                        567   Ok   
Team3   237     Ok                              452
```

So far, I've tried different ways to obtain it (using Left Join, Union, Case or a simple where) but when it comes to group by Team, I end up losing one or more rows of information.

I've created a SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fde53d/7

(The Schema is right, but the SQL Query is not as I obtain 3 rows for each Team, hence this question).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `left join`:

```
select t2.team, t2.type1, t11.status, t2.type2, t12.status, t2.type3, t13.status
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t11
     on t2.type1 = t11.itemnr left join
     table1 t12
     on t2.type2 = t12.itemnr left join
     table1 t13
     on t2.type3 = t13.itemnr;
```

Comment: Nice and quick, it seems my previous left join where not right. Thank you very much.